# Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: a custom Budget object

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic3, google-cloud-firestore

Below code works fine until today. But I don't know now it is not working and gives below error.Could you tell me why?

> Error: Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data.
>   Unsupported field value: a custom Budget object

```
 export class Project {
        id: string = null;
        name: string;
        budgetList?: Budget[];
    }

export class Budget {
    id: string;
    amount: number;
    contingency: number = 20;
    budgetGroup: BudgetGroup = new BudgetGroup();
    creationTime: string;
}
```

code:

```
  async create(data: DtoProject): Promise<Project> {
    try {
      const projectId: string = this.fireStore.createId();
      const budgets = this.budgetProvider.createBudgets(data.budgetList, projectId);//budgets
      const proj: Project = {
        id: data.id,
        name: data.name,
        budgetList: budgets,//here it has the error
      }
      proj.id = projectId;
      await this.fireStore.doc<Project>(`projects/${projectId}/`).set(proj));//project
      }
 }

  createBudgets(data: Budget[], projectId: string): Budget[] {
    let budgets: Budget[] = [];
    forEach(data, (d) => {
      const budgetId: string = this.fireStore.createId();
      d.id = budgetId;
      budgets.push(d);
      this.fireStore.doc<Budget>(`projects/${projectId}/budgets/${budgetId}`).set({
        id: budgetId,
        amount: d.amount,
        contingency: d.contingency,
        budgetGroup: d.budgetGroup,
        creationTime: moment().format()
      })
    })
    return budgets;
  }
```

Comment: I ran into this error when passing in a json object where some field values were unexpectedly null

Answer (score 107, accepted):

You have to **transform your array of budgets into  an array of pure JavaScript objects**.

First step:

```
const budgets = arrayOfBudget.map((obj)=> {return Object.assign({}, obj)});
```

Second step:

```
const proj: Project = {
      id: data.id,
      name: data.name,
      budgetList: budgets
    }
```

Then you are good to go.

By the way, when developing with a language that compiles to JavaScript you cannot use custom Objects. Instead, you have to use pure JavaScript objects to save in the Firestore Database.

For example, let's say you have this class below:

```
export class User {
        id: string;
        name: string;
    }
```

And you try to execute the following code:

```
 const user = new User();   
 this.db.collection('users').doc().set(user)
```

You will get an error like:

> invalid data. Data must be an object, but it was: a custom User object

Now if you try to execute this other line of code:

```
 this.db.collection('users').doc().set(Object.assign({}, user))
```

You will see that your object was saved in the database. Basically `Object.assign` does the same thing as:

```
this.db.collection('users').doc().set({id: user.id , name: user.name})
```

So make use of `Object.assign`, it will save you a lot of time.

**UPDATE**

As I have pointed out in a comment below, you can find what documentation says about **Custom objects** [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M81yZ.png). As you can see, there is a warning saying:

> // Web uses JavaScript objects

Below there is a screenshot of what the documentation says.

[image]

Comment: Beautifull, It is working perfectly fine. Thank you so much. But could you tell me why it is working some arrays and some not? e.g. I have another array in the same class like this. But no errors there.Any explanation? Do I need to convert that too as you showed above? `export class Project {
     memberList?: Member[];
}`

Comment: It is hard to tell since I am not seeing the rest of your code. But I strongly advise you to always convert your objects to pure JavaScript objects.

Comment: You're welcome. I am glad I could help you. :)

You can check what the documentation says about Custom Objects.
Here it is the link:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data

As you can see there is  a warning like: “ Web uses JavaScript objects”. Therefore make use of Object.assign.

Comment: What if you have a GeoPoint type field and you want to keep the type?

Comment: To avoid doing these "object to raw JS object" conversions time and time again, there is now a data converter class that you can use to trigger the said conversions at saving and retrieving times. Reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FirestoreDataConverter

Answer (score 23):

You can stringify the object and parse to object again to remove class names of the object.

```
const budgets = this.budgetProvider.createBudgets(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.budgetList)), projectId);
```

Comment: I tried other examples but this is the one for me that works perfectly with angularfire2.

Comment: I guessed this might be the way to fix this error too (in my own code) which is using a JS class user{}.  And this is the solution that worked for me, but it seems quite odd that it is necessary.

Answer (score 9):

You can also use the spread operator like:

```
this.fireStore
  .doc<Project>(`projects/${projectId}/`)
    .set( {...proj} ))
```

It work for me

Comment: This is by far the most simplest that didn't require much effort to fix the issue for me.

Comment: { ...proj } performs a shallow copy, so this approach works only if proj contains primitive types, not references to other types.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the add method with a new object copying all your values with the spread operator. This worked for me:

```
const user = new User();   
this.db.collection('users').add({...user});
```

Answer (score 0):

It work for me

```
proj.budgetList = {...budgets}


await this.fireStore.doc<Project>(`projects/${projectId}/`).set({...proj}));
```

Comment: This is nice alternative to `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(budgets))` (if field is undefined then it is add to object (this is the difference) and fb throws error - which chan be usefull)

Answer (score 0):

To anyone using `FirestoreDataConverter` here's how I did it for an array of object type `RecipeTag` inside an object of type `Recipe`.

//Location where I call to add a Recipe

```js
        const collectionRef = collection(db, collectionPath)
                             .withConverter(Recipe.firestoreConverter);
        await addDoc(collectionRef, recipe);
```

//`Recipe` model

```js
    public static firestoreConverter: FirestoreDataConverter<Recipe> = {
        toFirestore: (recipe: Recipe) => {
            return {
                title: recipe.title,
                recipeUrl: recipe.recipeUrl,
                imageLink: recipe.imageLink,
                tags: recipe.tags.map(tag => RecipeTag.firestoreConverter.toFirestore(tag))
            };
        },
        fromFirestore: (snapshot: DocumentSnapshot<DocumentData>) => {
            const data = snapshot.data() as Recipe
            return new Recipe(data)
        }
    }
```

//`RecipeTag` model

```js
    public static firestoreConverter: FirestoreDataConverter<RecipeTag> = {
        toFirestore: (recipe: RecipeTag) => {
            return {
                description: recipe.description,
                title: recipe.title,
            };
        },
        fromFirestore: (snapshot: DocumentSnapshot<DocumentData>) => {
            const data = snapshot.data() as RecipeTag
            return new RecipeTag(data)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue when trying to add a Map directly to Firestore (v9)

The issue was:

---

```
// Firestore module v9

// I was trying to add a Map to firestore

        userInterestsMap.forEach(async (v: Map<string, number>, k: string) => {
            const modelRef = doc(db, "model", k);
            await setDoc(modelRef, {
                'data': v // here is the issue
            });
        })
```

### Solution

```
        userInterestsMap.forEach(async (v: Map<string, number>, k: string) => {
            const modelRef = doc(db, "model", k);
            await setDoc(modelRef, {
                'data': Object.fromEntries(v) // here is the solution
            });
        })
```

---

So, basically, convert Map to Object

Answer (score -2):

Error is simply stating that data entered is invalid!

I've also faced the error from nowhere, which was because I removed the input field from interface which was supposed to get it's value and upload it in the document of some collection!

note: check your code in .ts file `firebase.firestore().collection("some_name").add() / set()` if some unnecessary field is there or not.