# ERROR Error: Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined (found in field activityId)

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to store my auto generated id into the documents field as.

```
  var act  =  this.afs.collection("activities").add({
  activityId = act.id,

    })
.then(function(docRef) {
    console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
});
```

but in the console there is an error occur. I am sure I am using wrong approach. Please help me how can I access auto id of my document? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: [Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48156234/function-documentreference-set-called-with-invalid-data-unsupported-field-val)

Comment: Shouldn't that be `activityId: act.id` instead of `activityId = act.id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use angularfire2 method `.createId()`. This will generate a random id locally.

```
let id = this.afs.createId();
this.afs.collection("activities").doc(id).set({
    activityId: id
});
```

Comment: are you getting same error? can you `console.log(act.id)`?

Comment: sorry my fault, i didn't notice you using angularfire2.