# getting error while contacting with database: Function Query.where() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: a custom U object

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently working on an app and I just started on the search filter but it is throwing the following error:

```
Function Query.where() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: a custom U object
```

and this is the code to the search screen

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TextInput, FlatList } from 'react-native';

import firebase from 'firebase';

export default function Search() {
  const [patients, setPatients] = useState([]);

  const fetchPatients = (searchTxt) => { 
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection('Patients')
      .where('doctorEmail', '==', firebase.auth().currentUser.email)
      .where('patientName', '>=', searchTxt)
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        let patients = snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
          var data = doc.data()
          var id = doc.id
          return {id,...data}
        })
        setPatients(patients)
      })
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput
        placeholder="Search..."
        style={{padding:100,marginTop:100}}
        onChange={(searchTxt) => {fetchPatients(searchTxt)
        console.log(patients)}}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

This is my database structure

[image]

[image: This is the last part of a patient document]

if you have any idea on how to fix this issue please let me know...Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in how the  `firebase.auth().currentUser.email` & `searchText` is being sent to the query.

Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48156234/function-documentreference-set-called-with-invalid-data-unsupported-field-val) out.

Comment: Thanks @Huthafia Muayyad...Its working fine now

Comment: You're most welcome! Kindly consider marking this as an answer to your question, I'd appreciate it :)

Comment: And also wanted to let you know that after I fixed the issue with your answer I also had to change the onChange property to onChangeText for it to work